# How to view only the first row or a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, drupal

I want to view one row of a table in a MySQL database to see what kind of information is stored in the table. What is the MySQL command and syntax to accomplish this, after `> use [database_name]` This table has over 3 Million rows, so I don't want to risk printing them all.

MySQL Version 14.14 Distrib 5.5.53, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I probably posted in the wrong SE community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `LIMIT 1` to your query. Ex:

`SELECT * 
FROM Users 
LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use LIMIT for limiting row count. Like this:

```
SELECT column from someTable LIMIT 1;
```

If you don't know what kind of columns the table has, you can check them using DESC:

```
DESC table;
```

Heres a small example built with sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/57697